# Make custom cell's ( created with autolayout) height to zero

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I want to make height of a custom tableview cell to zero, which was created with autolayout. Basically I have container view added as subview to cell.contentview. Container view's top, bottom, left and right are pinned to content view's  top, bottom, left and right. Under certain condition I want to make height as 0.

I iterated through content views's constraints and found this constrain causing the problem.

*NSLayoutConstraint:0x1369d8670 UITableViewCellContentView:0x1369b1a90.height == 48*

This constraint is added by default by tableview.

**Things I Tried** : I removed all subviews of container view. But this does not make cell height to zero.

**Things I don't want to do**:

1. I dont want to reload entire tableview coz I will be having many rows with many subviews.
2. I don't want to delete row

How can I set height to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload particular row so it will call tableview's delegate method for height change `heightForRorAtIndexpath`. You can set the height 1 when you programmatically reload particular row. You can store temporary `indexpath` which you want to make zero.

Clip all the subiviews by `clipsToBounds=YES`

call `[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];`

Comment: Tried your suggesstion but no luck. Cell's content view is still visible. I went through the constraints of content view and came across the constraint thats causing <NSLayoutConstraint:0x1369d8670 UITableViewCellContentView:0x1369b1a90.height == 48>.

Comment: Reloading particular cell and returning 0 in `heightForRorAtIndexpath` did the trick.